# Can you load OKTA_CONFIG from an API call in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, okta

I have been trying to load the OKTA_CONFIG from an API call for some time now but have had no luck. I would like it to work similar to how APP_INITILIZER works where when a promise is returned from a factory provider the application won't start until the promise is resolved. Is this possible? When I try I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘_oktaUserAgent’). It will work if I do not use a promise and instead return the created OktaAuth object directly. Please see the code examples below.

AppModule

```
export function initializeApp(
  service: AppinitilizerService
): () => Promise<any> {
  return () => service.initializeApp();
}

export function initializeOkta(
  service: OktainitilizerService
): () => Promise<any> {
  return () => service.initializeOkta();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    OktaAuthModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [AppinitilizerService],
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: OKTA_CONFIG,
      useFactory: initializeOkta,
      deps: [OktainitilizerService],
      multi: false,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppInitilizer Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppinitilizerService {

  constructor() { }

  initializeApp(): Promise<any> {
    //simulate api call to load configuration.
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true)
      }, 5000)
    })
  }

}
```

OktaInitilizer Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OktainitilizerService {

  constructor() { }

  initializeOkta(): Promise<any> {
    //simulate api call to load configuration.
    return new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        //Would use values returned from the API call for issuer and client id.
        const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
          issuer: 'https://{yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default',
          clientId: '{yourClienId}',
          redirectUri: '{yourRedirectUri}',
          scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
          pkce: true,
        })
        resolve({oktaAuth})
      }, 10000)
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to load the config before the app loads, not using APP_INITIALIZER, so you'll need to do so at bootstrap time.

You can do this via a `fetch` call in `main.ts` and pass in the config response into the app as a provider in `platformBrowserDynamic` method call.

Check out [this post for more details on how to do load configs from external APIs](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/02/24/angular-async-config) and pass the configuration into the `OktaAuthModule`.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue.

Comment: Your post says: "Summary of loading configuration from an external API:

Load configuration from an API and provide the config to the application. Depending on your needs, the configuration loading may occur during bootstrapping or via `APP_INITIALIZER`." Do you have an example how to make it work with APP_INITIALIZER`?

Comment: @kost no, the configuration to initialize Okta must be done during boostrap, not using the `APP_INITIALIZER`, per this quote from the post


> However, in our case, we need the auth configuration _in order_ to initialize. So, we need to finish loading the configuration before initializing the app, which we can do when bootstrapping.